# How to depend on a react addon from a reusable component on npm?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I have created a reusable react component which uses a react addon (`react-addons-shallow-compare`).

What is the preferred way to depend on this addon to publish on npm? `dependency` or `peerDependency`?

For now I'm doing it as a `dependency`:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.0.2",
},
```

This way, people using my component don't have to explicitly also install `react-addons-shallow-compare`.

The addon has itself a peerDepdendency on react.

There's no concern of duplicated code since internally that addon just does this: `module.exports = require('react/lib/shallowCompare');`

I do however have to update my small lib when a new react version is published so the `peerDependency` on react can be met.

What are other library authors doing?

Should I skip this entirely and rely on https://www.npmjs.com/package/shallowequal for instance?